# Put class instance to class constant in initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In one of my old apps, I'm using several API connectors - like AWS or Mandill as example.

For some reason (may be I saw it somewhere, don't remember), I using class constant to initialize this objects on init stage of application.

As example:
**/initializers/mandrill.rb:**

```
require 'mandrill'
MANDRILL = Mandrill::API.new ENV['MANDRILL_APIKEY']
```

Now I can access `MANDRILL` class constant of my application in any method and use it. (full path `MyApplication::Application::MANDRILL`, or just `MANDRILL`). All working fine, example:

```
def update_mandrill
  result = MANDRILL.inbound.update_route id, pattern, url
end
```

**The question is:** it is good practice to use such class constants? Or better create new class instance in every method that using this instance, like in example:

```
def update_mandrill
  require 'mandrill'
  mandrill = Mandrill::API.new ENV['MANDRILL_APIKEY']
  result = mandrill.inbound.update_route id, pattern, url
end
```

Comment: TBH, I think its a good practice. It makes your code *DRY*

Comment: I don't see any harm there, I use such constant object for s3 too..

Comment: apart from making code DRY, curious - how this affect memory using? In case of class constant we don't create instance of `MANDRILL` in every method call and using instance that already in memory (so this is good)? Or this working somehow in another way?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.

It's very handy approach but it may have cons in some scenarios.

Imagine you have a constant that either takes a lot of time to initialize or it loads a lot of data into memory. When its initialization takes long you essentially degrade app boot time (which may or may not be a problem, usually it will in development). 
If it loads a lot of data into memory it may turn out it's gonna be a problem when running rake tasks for example which load entire environment. You may hit memory boundaries in use cases in which you essentially do not need this data at all.
I know one application which load a lot of data during boot - and it's done very deliberately. Sure, use case is a bit uncommon, but still.

Another thing to consider is - imagine, you're trying to establish connection to external service like Mongo or anything else. If this service is unavailable (what happens) your application won't be able to boot. Maybe this service is essential for app to work, and without it it would be "useless" anyway, but it's also possible that you essentially stop everything because storage in which you keeps log does not work.

I'm not saying you shouldn't use it as you suggested - I do it also in my apps, but you should be aware of potential drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks. This answer organise my thoughts. Intuitively I understood this  and creating such things as Redis connection as example directly in methods. So  - can we say that we can place some small instruments like some independent api connector classes to class constants, but aware to do this with external services?

But in another point of view - if my application using Mongo as database, and Mongo is unreachable - what sense in loading this app? It will not work in any case without DB :)

Comment: IMHO, yes. Sometimes that may be necessary, but then it should be done  deliberately, so you could think of potential solutions to problems which you may encounter before they occur.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pre-creating a pseudo-constant object (like that api client) is usually a good idea. However, there is, approximately, a thousand ways go about it and the constant is not on top of my personal list.

These days I usually go with setting it in the env files.

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.email_client = Mandrill::API.new ENV['MANDRILL_APIKEY'] # the real thing

# config/environments/test.rb
config.email_client = a_null_object # something that conforms to the same api, but does absolutely nothing

# config/environments/development.rb 
config.email_client = a_dev_object # post to local smtp, or something
```

Then you refer to the client like this:

```
Rails.application.configuration.email_client
```

And the correct behaviour will be picked up in each env.

If I don't need this per-env variation, then I either use some kind of singleton object (`EmailClient.get`) or a global variable in the initializer (`$email_client`). It can be argued that a constant is better than global variable, semantically and because it raises a warning when you try to re-assign it. But I like that global variable stands out more. You see right away that it's something special. (*And then again, it's only #3 in the list, so I don't do it very often.*).

Comment: I agree - but Mandrill it my question was an example. It can be any other lib that contains method to connect to some API's - AWS as example. Or some custom lib.

Comment: @OleksiiBaidan: doesn't matter, the same advice applies.